# AngularJS - ng-click firing twice

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have this piece of code (showing only the relevant section):

```
:
:
<span ng-repeat="One_Selected_Method in This_Page.Parameters_and_Methods[$index].Selected_Test_Methods" 
      class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">
    {{One_Selected_Method}}
    <span> 
        <!-- The use of "$parent.$index" is to account for the nesting where the actually needed index is that of the parent -->
        <button id="Param_Method_{{$parent.$index}}_{{One_Selected_Method}}" 
                class="button" 
                ng-click="Remove_Selected_Method($parent.$index,One_Selected_Method)" 
                style="border-radius: 20px;background:red"> 
            <font color="white">X</font>
        </button> 
    </span>
</span>
:
:
```

It is part of an already large application.

The problem is that when clicking at the button, the function `Remove_Selected_Method` is invoked twice and hence two deletions take place.

Also tried `;$event.stopPropagation();` after the invocation of the `Remove_Selected_Method` but no change of behavior. Can't figure out why.

### Edit

I should note that there are many places throughout the application in which `ng-click` is used to add pills, tabs, records, etc. as well as to remove them. The above is the first time I have this strange behavior.

### Edit 2

It turns out that the second invocation of the function is caused by the `splice` I use to remove the entry within the function `Remove_Selected_Method`: added a log at the beginning of the function and, with the splice, it is shown twice, but after commenting out the splice, only once.

I don't quite understand why though...

Comment: Silly question: are you not including angular twice?

Comment: are you using use same ng-controller in HTML code twice?

Comment: Thank you @F.Almeida for your comment. I don't think so. If I had, I would had seen this behavior loooooong ago.

Comment: Thank you @HrishikeshKale for your comment. No, the declaration of the controller appears only once in the page. Moreover, there is another button in the same page that adds the entities (one by one) that the function `Remove_Selected_Method` deletes (when clicked), and the former function (the one that adds) is invoked only once when the corresponding button is clicked.

Comment: @FDavidov one more question: is that HTML in a controller view or directive? Where is the function you are calling on click?

Comment: @F.Almeida, the page is, in fact, **included**. The invoked functions are within the controller of the included page.

Comment: @FDavidov are you using angular latest version?

Comment: @F.Almeida, AngularJS 1.5.8.

Comment: id="Param_Method_{{$parent.$index}}_{{One_Selected_Method}}" ... so pretty

Comment: @PetrAveryanov yeah... I understand what you are implying. The issue is that I have a table with a variable number of rows, each representing an object; attached to each object, there is a variable number of elements. So, `$parent.$index` is the index of the record in the table, while `One_Selected_Method` represents on of the elements. That's the way I use to provide unique IDs to DOM elements (in cases like this one).

Comment: I just think that your function is run twice, cause this element is addressed from somewhere else. And that is what this id for. And thats why you should not set weird ids on elements - you do not need them, cause when something stops working you cant understand what is run from where... As a practical advice - remove id, change function name and check if it runs twice or not.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov, just tried what you suggested and got the same result. As per the IDs, it was part of an attempt to understand/fix the issue. I can remove them (though it doesn't solve the problem).

Comment: @F.Almeida, Please refer to **EDIT-2**.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov, Please refer to **EDIT-2**.